# How to refer to a button that is in the list Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create an app in android studio.  I've only recently started to get interested in this and ran into a problem.  As planned, for each move in the game, the player presses several buttons, I would like to put the id of these buttons in a separate list, and when necessary, use this list to change the color of all those buttons that are in this list

What i did:

I have the list->

```
val move_list: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()
```

When the player presses the button, I add its id to move_list

```
fun for_btn_buba2(view: View){
    move_list.add(buba2.id)
```

In activity_main.xml my button seems like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buba2"
    android:text="Buba 2"
    ...
    android:onClick="for_btn_buba2"/>
```

And on click of another button i wanted to insert code like this:

```
move_list[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorString:"#FFFC9D45"))
```

move_list[0] means id for button buba2

In python it can be, but it isnt python)

How can I change the color of the button through the list index with the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I suggest you indicate the type of what is in the list, which is `Int` so like

```
val move_list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
```

Then you can probably do this in the onClick of the other button

```
findViewById<View>(move_list[0]).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC9D45"))
```

or to do it to all

```
move_list.forEach { 
    findViewById<View>(it).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC9D45"))
}
```

---

I also notice you directly refer to `buba2` in it the `for_btn_buba2`. I have the feeling that you are writing this function for every `buba`. This is unnecessary. You can get the id from the `view` parameter because that is in fact the same id. So do

```
fun for_btn_buba(view: View){
    move_list.add(view.id)
}
```

then you can give each buba the same `for_btn_buba` as `android:onClick`

---

Alternatively you don't even work with ids at all and make it a

```
val move_list: MutableList<View> = mutableListOf()
```

and then do

```
fun for_btn_buba(view: View){
    move_list.add(view)
}
```

and then you can actually change the background like you wrote it:

```
move_list[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC9D45"))
```

or

```
move_list.forEach { 
    it.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC9D45"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i hope i can help someone in the future too.